# python - replace ALL values in a nested dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, replace, nested

I would like to replace all VALUES in a nested dictionary with values from a list.
Been searching for hours and can't seem to find a solution.

So I read values from a txt file and puts them in a list, then I want to replace all the dict values with the values from the list.

This would work well since all items in the list is the same amount of values in the nested dict.

This is my code so far:

```
def print_hi(name):

     
    file = open("list.txt")
    list = file.read()
    file.close()

    newlist = list.split("\n")

    file = open("lang.json")
    jsonString = file.read()
    file.close()

    jsonObject = json.loads(jsonString)

    for key, value in jsonObject.items():
     jsonObject[key] = newlist[]
     print(jsonObject)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_hi('PyCharm')
```

Example how my .json and .txt looks like.

```
    {
  "general": {
    "accessibility": {
      "skip_to_content": "Skip to content",
      "close_modal": "Close (esc)",
      "close": "Close",
      "learn_more": "Learn more"
    },
```

```
Hello there
How are you 
Nice to meet you
Read more
```

The outcome im searching:

```
  "general": {
    "accessibility": {
      "skip_to_content": "Hello there",
      "close_modal": "How are you",
      "close": "Nice to meet you",
      "learn_more": "Read more"
    },
```

Kind regards

Comment: It's much easier to answer a question if you give a concrete example. We don't know the  contents of `list.txt` of `lang.json` so none of your code is runnable for us. Instead, just make a simple list and dict that shows what you are trying to do and the result you hope to get in a way that we can copy / paste and run it.

Comment: Hi there! Good point, just updated it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's s liner assignment of values we can iterate through the JSON object and replace its values. Like this

```
for k in jsonObject:
    for sub_k in jsonObject[k]:
        try:
           jsonObject[k][sub_k] = new_list.pop(0)
        except IndexError:
            print('List empty')

print(jsonObject)
{'meta': {'tags': 'Hello there', 'page': 'How are you '},
 '404': {'title': 'Nice to meet you', 'subtext_html': 'Read more'}}
```

Comment: Worked like charm, thank you!

Comment: Since the json is nested a bit more than what my example shows it skipps some parts :/

Comment: My fault for not making that clear, i have updated the json example if you want to look.